# How to automatically #derive(Something) on every struct(possibly with filtering)?

Tags: rust, traits

Is there a way to get the Rust compiler to add derives on all structs, possibly with some kind of matching, like only structs in X crate, or maybe recursively apply #derives? I would rather not vendor those crates because it'd be a lot of work to keep them up to date.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Rust compiler does not provide such a facility.

Answer (score 1):

You can't derive traits for types outside of your own crate. So you have two options:

- Submit a PR to the crate in question, to add the implementations. Many projects will accept changes that implement common traits like `serde::Serialize` etc, provided they are feature-gated
- Use wrapper types and implement the traits there. e.g. if the type in question is `Uuid` from the `uuid` crate:

  ```
  pub struct MyUuid(uuid::Uuid);

  impl MyTrait for MyUuid {
     // etc
  }
  ```

Note that you can't derive traits that need to know the fields of third party types because the tokens will not be available.